# What's the difference of FaceTime App that came installed in my Retina Macbook Pro and the one that is in Mac App Store for $0.99?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, applications, mac-appstore, facetime

I checked that both apps (pre-installed and paid) have different version numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FaceTime in the App Store is really only meant for users of 10.6 Snow Leopard.  As of 10.7 Lion, FaceTime comes pre-installed.

I'm not sure why Apple was charging for FaceTime in the first place.  Perhaps just testing the Apple Store sales model.